# Adding an splist instance to an Application page programmatically through xaml/backend c#

Tags: splist

I have created a custom list which I wish to put inside an application page, since I wish to be able to filter what is shown inside the list to the content which is related to the user.

Is there any tutorial which I can use to see the code in xaml or through page load such that I am able to add an instance of the custom list to the application page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways to do what you want!

this is a simple way:

in your aspx page you can add a gridview control. It will display what ever column you specifiy!
I have called it grid and building a custom list as i dont want to display all the columns but rather only a few:

```
<div style=" position:relative"> 
    <asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="95%" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="30" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" OnRowDataBound="grid_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="grid_PageIndexChanging" >  
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="Request ref" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Business_x0020_area" HeaderText="Business area" />     
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

so i have three columns that i want the user to see: ID, Title and Business area. I have named business area like this `Business_x0020_area` because it has a space and you need to fill it in with `_x0020_` as im calling the internal name of a field!!

if you just want to display all columns than do it like so:

```
<div style=" position:relative"> 
    <asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" Width="95%" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="30" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" OnRowDataBound="grid_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="grid_PageIndexChanging" >  
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

same as above appart from not adding the columns as its auto generated `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` instead of `AutoGenerateColumns="false"`.

both have paging enabled and show a max of 30 rows per page!

now goto the aspx.cs and on the onload function you can bind the grid to the list:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://yoursiteurl:2013/"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("YourSubsite"))
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists["USER"];
                SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;
                grid.DataSource = items.GetDataTable();
                grid.DataBind();     
            }
        }       
    }
```

on the page load event its getting the spsite object from a given url, you then get the spweb object from the spsite and opening a specific web that holds the list as an example:

```
http://yoursiteurl:2013/YourSubsite
```

moving on... we have a list within the site YourSubsite, so you would get it using the SPList object.

```
SPList list = web.Lists["USER"];
```

the above is using the newly created spweb to look for a list called `USERS`, it returns a SPList object and we called it list so we can manipulate it.

```
                SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;
                grid.DataSource = items.GetDataTable();
                grid.DataBind();
```

we now want to get all the items within the list and storing it within the SPListItemCollection object, we do this so we can get a datatable out of all items to populate the grids datasource for binding:

```
grid.DataSource = items.GetDataTable();
```

the above is getting a datatable from the list to set it as a datasource for out grid that we made within the aspx page. lastly we need to bind the result:

```
grid.DataBind();
```

......

the last stage is to bind the paging event so when you click on the next page it would get the correct results by rebinding:

```
    protected void grid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        grid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        grid.DataBind();
    }
```